# Want to show the first index(date-time-timezone) of the array which ends with a comma

Tags: javascript, arrays

const arr = [2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489,
2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489,
2021-02-28 20:29:53.922528, 2021-02-28 20:39:17.784694,
2021-02-28 20:41:11.267998, 2021-02-28 20:41:45.165464,
2021-02-28 20:47:16.741279, 2021-02-28 20:47:16.741279];

From the above array I want to show "2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489" this portion which separate with a comma.

Comment: its hard to understand what exactly you are looking for, please add example or  code sample.

Comment: It would be much helpful if you let us know what you've tried so far and added a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: From API I've got this array. Now I need to show the first portion of this array. That's the main thing actually. @RahulR.

Comment: This is not a legal Javascript array.  You need quotes around each entry to make them into strings. You should see an error in your browser's dev tools console something like: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: @AHaworth yeah. But I got this from api. That's why I can't find any way to show that way. This loginTime is the actual API data.                                                                                                          loginTime: "[2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 2]"

Comment: OK, what exactly did you get from the api? A string that looks like this 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 etc or one that has the JS already as part of it?

Comment: @AHaworth as I mentioned earlier, I want to show the first portion. Is that possible? FYI I'm working on a Angular project. Actually Typescript but you know there is minimal difference with JS

Comment: I put up an answer assuming what you got back from the api was a string of just the bit between the [ and ]. If the api is giving you the square brackets as well, get rid of them first using replace on the string and then do the splitting as in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what the api gives you is a Javascript string, you can split it at each comma into an array of strings and then pick out the first entry.

```js
function whatyougetbackfromtheapi() {
  return '2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 20:29:53.922528, 2021-02-28 20:39:17.784694, 2021-02-28 20:41:11.2679<98, 2021-02-28 20:41:45.165464, 2021-02-28 20:47:16.741279, 2021-02-28 20:47:16.741279';
}
const str = whatyougetbackfromtheapi();
const arr = str.split(',');
alert(arr[0]);
```

If what you get back from the api is a string which includes the square brackets get rid of them before doing the split:

```js
function whatyougetbackfromtheapi() {
  return '[2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 18:21:08.244489, 2021-02-28 20:29:53.922528, 2021-02-28 20:39:17.784694, 2021-02-28 20:41:11.2679<98, 2021-02-28 20:41:45.165464, 2021-02-28 20:47:16.741279, 2021-02-28 20:47:16.741279]';
}
let str = whatyougetbackfromtheapi();
str = str.replace('[', '');
str = str.replace(']', '');
const arr = str.split(',');
alert(arr[0]);
```